# Text (non-anchor tag) not aligned in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display text within a navbar which is not wrapped within an anchor tag.  All the documentation I found shows only the class `navbar-brand` which makes the text too big. I thought I could simply put the text within `<li></li>` and exclude the anchor tag, but the element loses the alignment within the navbar when I do this.

Here is what it is displaying:

[image: text in navbar not lining up]

Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand"> NavBar Brand </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li> Logged in as Foobar</li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Submit Help desk Ticket</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>            
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class `navbar-text`

```
<li class="navbar-text">Logged in as Foobar</li>
```

Comment: Very nice, didn't know about that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom class or only the `<a>` tag

```css
.navbar .navbar-nav .login {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar .navbar-nav .login {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button> <a class="navbar-brand"> NavBar Brand </a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a>Logged in as Foobar</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Submit Help desk Ticket</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<hr>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar2"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button> <a class="navbar-brand"> NavBar Brand </a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="login">Logged in as Foobar

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Submit Help desk Ticket</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```